# What is using all my memory on WordPress VPS hosting

Tags: performance, vps, hosting, memory-usage

I have a WordPress site hosted on a VPS Centos5_x64_cpanel system with 1Gb of memory.

Recently I have been having a lot of issues with the site performance and emails from the hosting company stating that the server overloads.

Today I got this email:

```
We have reboot the VPS ##.##.###.### , as it overload again

Normal: empty
HighMem: empty
50559 pagecache pages
Swap cache: add 20318560, delete 20312638, find 3426118/4492729, race 2780+11340
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 2097144kB
```

I also get this email quite a few times a day:

```
The chkservd sub-process with pid 11939 ran for 4949 seconds. This sub-process was terminated when it exceeded the time allowed between checks, which is 600 seconds. To determine why, you can check /var/log/chkservd.log and /usr/local/cpanel/logs/tailwatchd_log.

You likely received this notification as a symptom of a larger problem. If your server is experiencing a high load, we recommend investigating the cause. If you continue to receive this notification, it is likely that your system is unable to handle demand or a misconfiguration is delaying restarts.

If you are sure that no misconfigurations exist, you should consider gradually increasing the following options in WHM's "Tweak Settings" feature: "The number of times ChkServd will allow a previous check to complete before terminating the check" and/or "The number of seconds between ChkServd service checks".
Server:     ###.#########.##
Primary IP:     ##.##.###.###
Service:    chkservd
Notification Type:  hang
Memory Information:     

    Used: 820MB
    Available: 208MB
    Installed: 1024MB 

Load Information:   76.53 75.24 80.24
Uptime:     0 days, 8 hours, 14 seconds
IOStat Information:     

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.97    0.01    0.80   13.19    0.01   84.02
Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda1             18.57       360.59       132.67   10712202    3941360
sda2            422.54       995.39      2497.02   29570128   74179496

ChkServd Version:   15.1
```

The site is nothing special and has a few plugins installed.

I suspect that it could be a plugin causing the excessive memory usage. I am fairly new to WHM so is there a way or a log file I can check to see what is using all the memory. If so where would I look and are there any tests I can run to check if it is a plugin and which plugin it is.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of a Hit and Trial test for this, as I don't think there any any tool which can tell you which specific plugin is using the memory.

For this, you can run the top command on the server, and start disabling your plugins one by one.

As soon as you hit the specific plugin, you will notice the RAM getting free up. That is the only way I can think of right now for checking the memory issue for plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Can I ask what kind of aspects consume RAM. IE Is it all the database queries, the remote server calls to the Social Networking sites etc?

Comment: Well, it depends, Database takes it's own share of the memory, but the main issue with you seems to be with the Apache/Web Server you are using. You can again check the same with top command. 

Run the *top* command and then press *m*. It will sort things on the memory usage basis and you can see which which process of your machine is taking most of the memory.